# What does breaking the discrete logarithm problem imply for anonymity?

Tags: privacy, cryptography, quantum-computing

If the discrete logarithm problem is broken (either through a mathematical breakthrough or a quantum computer) what are the implications for the **history** of Monero transactions?

Will past anonymity be broken?

With Tornado Cash (ZKP-based) for example, breaking the discrete logarithm problem will allow to forge proofs and drain the existing fund pools, but anonymity will not be broken.

Also, as an interesting aside, re-implementing Tornado Cash using the FRI protocol (ex. zk-STARK) will be immune to discrete logarithm breaks.